# Restrict Searchable field in Lightning

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, lookup, search

Look Search is working differently in Classic and lightning. We have a look up field on the Cases to the Products table. As shown below when I search for the Product in the case in Classic I get only one record back

[image]

In lightning the same case I tried do a look up for the same product it returns 50 + records. Looks like the 7914 is looked against name as well. End users are not very happy with this as they have to scroll through and find the Product code with 7914

[image]

Is there a way I can restrict the Searchable field to be only Product code and not on the name. I changed the Search layout but looks like it removes the fields displayed on the search result though. Any suggestion/recommendation on fixing this?